# Covariant Derivative of Basis Vector

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

I understand that the covariant derivative of a covariant vector is as follows
$$\nabla_\mu V_\nu=\partial_\mu V_\nu-\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}V_\lambda$$
But for basis vectors (which are also covariant), why is it that
$$\nabla_\mu \textbf{e}_\nu=\partial_\mu \textbf{e}_\nu+\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}\textbf{e}_\lambda$$
Is there a proof for this?

I also have another issue. Using the definition of Christoffel symbols,
$$\partial_\mu \textbf{e}_\nu=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}\textbf{e}_\lambda$$
substituting this to the covariant derivative, I get
$$\nabla_\mu \textbf{e}_\nu=2\partial_\mu \textbf{e}_\nu=2\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}\textbf{e}_\lambda$$
What is going on here?

Comment: You’re mixing up what is a component vs what is a vector, and co/contravariant is also off, and your definition is wrong. The correct definition is $\nabla_{\mu}\mathbf{e}_{\nu}=\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}\mathbf{e}_{\lambda}$ (more properly, $\nabla_{\mathbf{e}_{\mu}}\mathbf{e}_{\nu}=\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}\mathbf{e}_{\lambda}$). Note that $\partial_{\mu}\mathbf{e}_{\nu}$ is (aside from $\Bbb{R}^n$ with Cartesian coordinates) completely meaningless string of symbols. All these definitions are clearly presented in a RIemannian geometry book (e.g Lee or Do Carmo, or O’Neill, or Spivak etc).

Comment: @peek-a-boo $\nabla_\mu \textbf{e}_\nu=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}\textbf{e}_\lambda$ is news to me. Alright I will start reading formal books on Riemannian Geometry, thanks!